# WARNING:tensorflow:Detecting that an object or model or tf.train.Checkpoint is being deleted with unrestored values

Tags: python, pycharm

I am runnning the following Python codes:

```
import librosa
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout,Bidirectional
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import seaborn as sns

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, GlobalMaxPool1D,Dropout
```

but experienced the following warning messages, hence affecting the results:

```
2023-07-12 18:19:52.359271: W tensorflow/tsl/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:83] Allocation of 393084928 exceeds 10% of free system memory.
1/5 [=====>........................] - ETA: 1s2023-07-12 18:19:52.585311: W tensorflow/tsl/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:83] Allocation of 393084928 exceeds 10% of free system memory.
2/5 [===========>..................] - ETA: 0s2023-07-12 18:19:52.810294: W tensorflow/tsl/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:83] Allocation of 393084928 exceeds 10% of free system memory.
3/5 [=================>............] - ETA: 0s2023-07-12 18:19:53.040396: W tensorflow/tsl/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:83] Allocation of 393084928 exceeds 10% of free system memory.
5/5 [==============================] - 1s 201ms/step
WARNING:tensorflow:Detecting that an object or model or tf.train.Checkpoint is being deleted with unrestored values. See the following logs for the specific values in question. To silence these warnings, use `status.expect_partial()`. See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Checkpoint#restorefor details about the status object returned by the restore function.
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer._variables.1
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer._variables.2
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer._variables.3
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer._variables.4
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer._variables.5
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer._variables.6
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer._variables.7
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer._variables.8
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer._variables.9
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer._variables.10
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer._variables.11
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer._variables.12
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer._variables.13
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer._variables.14
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer._variables.15
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer._variables.16
```

As a newbie in Python coding, please help me to resolve the warning messages.

Comment: There are only imports in the code you pasted, where are the actual functions?

Comment: I ran the same codes in Juypter notebook and it did not prompt the same warning messages. I thought it is platform related issues. Question can be closed.